# Django channels redis settings when deploying on aws behind a load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, django-rest-framework, redis, django-channels

I am deploying my django application on aws using docker. Currently I am deploying it by adding a redis service in my docker compose file. And letting channel redis connect to the docker redis service.

This works fine when I have only one server. But in production I have multiple servers behind a load balancer so at that time I need to have a shared instance of redis which multiple servers can share. What are my options?

```
docker-compose file
redis:
      image: redis
      hostname: redis-container
      expose:
        - 6379
web:
     depends_on:
         -redis



settings.py
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("redis-container", 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: is your redis running in a separate docker compose file?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a separate docker-compose file containing redis what you can do is

- Create a external docker network
- docker network create -d bridge my-bridge-network
- add this network in all of your compose files, so they have access to same network

in your docker-compose.yml files u can add this line for version 3.4 at the end

```
networks: 
  default: 
    external: 
      name: my-bridge-network
```

all of the compose environment using this network will be able to use redis by calling its container name